# How to build NS-3 to use C++0x/C++11 libraries?

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, waf, ns-3

I need to use data structures like unordered_map within my code in network simulator NS-3.
It is using waf builder to compile the source code. 
I am confused that where should I add -std=c++0x to be added to compiler flags? 
I tried appending it to CXXFlags in main wscript file using:

```
module.env.append_value('CXXFLAGS', '-std=c++0x');
```

But still I am getting this error:

> This file requires compiler and library support for the upcoming ISO C++ standard, C++0x. This support is currently experimental, and must be enabled with the -std=c++0x or -std=gnu++0x compiler options.   C/C++ Problem

Should I also add any library to my waf module as well?

P.S: My GCC version is 4.4

Update: After updating to 4.7 I get this error:

```
error: #error This file requires compiler and library support for the ISO C++ 2011 standard. This support is currently experimental, and must be enabled with the -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 compiler options.
```

Is there a way to tell compiler to use 0x instead of 11?

Comment: Have you considered using a GCC version that's more recent than 2 years ago?

Comment: Try to get a newer version of GCC (I would say *at least* 4.6, but even 4.7.1 if you uses C++11).

Comment: @NicolBolas I updated my GCC and G++ to 4.7 and re-configured NS but now when it reaches the same point it gives this error: error: #error This file requires compiler and library support for the ISO C++ 2011 standard. This support is currently experimental, and must be enabled with the -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 compiler options.

Comment: Just to give an update. I was trying to compile NS3 on Ubuntu Server 12.04 LTS with GCC 4.7.2 Linaro tool-chain manually compiled and the "-std=c++11x" flag enabled. The number of errors this produces does indicate that NS3 is still incompatible with C++11.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is the solution:

First of all upgrading GCC to 4.7 for Ns-3 will cause more errors due to changes in standard and does not solve the problem. So I changed gcc and g++ back to 4.4.3.

But in order to get rid of this error (as it says) this option should be added to CXXFLAGS:

```
-std=c++0x
```

To add an option to CXXFLAG you can use this:

```
CXXFLAGS="-std=c++0x" ./waf configure
```

or if you want to add options to waf configure:

```
CXXFLAGS="-std=c++0x" ./waf -d debug --enable-examples --enable-tests configure
```